# "The people with whom you are talking" vs. "The people you are talking with"

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to say

> "One of the disadvantages of chatrooms is that you do not know the people with whom you are talking"?

I think it is better to say *"the people you are talking with"* but I do not know if the first option would be possible.

Comment: Both are correct, and there is no change in meaning. This is an example of [Pied-piping](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/55129/15299), which is characteristic of a more formal style. Which may or may not be appropriate for a chat room.

Comment: Related (in numeric not relateness order though): http://english.stackexchange.com/q/16
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3910
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/19020
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/20417
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/45401
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/51667
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/71866
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/96822
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/102256

Comment: Saying *"the people you are talking to"* would be the best way.

Comment: Even better _the people you're talking to_. That's what would be said; `Pronoun` + _`be`_ is almost always contracted in speech. And often in chat rooms, where the contractions often surface as unapostrophicated _Im, im, your, youre, hes, shes, were, there, theyre, their_. Clearly leading inevitably to the breakdown of Western Civilization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

‘The people with whom you are talking’ is formal bordering on the pompous. Your alternative is more appropriate for most occasions, but speakers of British English, at least, would be more likely to say ‘. . . is that you don’t know who you’re talking to’.

Comment: Anybody would say it that way, Barrie.  At least, so I hope.

Comment: Saying "talking with" is also formal and unnecessary. *Talking to* would be more natural and better.